# How to set the language for formulas to English instead of the default Excel language?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Excel 2007 is installed in French language. So all formulas are in French, which is not handy:

```
=RECHERCHEV(...)
```

instead of

```
=VLOOKUP(...)
```

Question: **how to set the language to English *for formulas*, even if Excel is installed in French?**

Comment: Refer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5Sp1P3Oye8

Answer (score 0):

1. File -> Option -> Language -> Add a language.
2. Select English. Click Install.
3. Move it up to be the default language.

Comment: To add to this answer: It is not possible to change the language of only the formulas. You set the language for the program, and the formula language changes with it.

Comment: Thanks Reddy. This isn't available in Excel 2007, is it? (I didn't find it).

Comment: @Basj Sorry, forgot you stated Excel 2007. Seems that Adding language packs started with 2010 (I might be wrong) See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-editing-or-authoring-language-or-set-language-preferences-in-office-663d9d94-ca99-4a0d-973e-7c4a6b8a827d#ID0EBBF=2010,_2013,_2016

Comment: If that's the case, then you will need to intall Excel 2007 English version.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Feel free to add this into the answer for completeness, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Basj  According to [this](http://howtomicrosoftofficetutorials.blogspot.com/2017/06/add-language-or-set-language.html), it is possible to add the language pack in Office 2007. Please try them before I can add it as answer.